# Does apt install --reinstall delete config files?

Tags: apt, virtualbox

I want to reinstall Oracle VirtualBox as it isn't working (`The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module available for the current kernel (5.3.0-7629-generic) or it failed to load. Please recompile the kernel module by and install it by sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`)

What I'm worried about is that whether my current virtual machine gets deleted after using `sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox`.

I tried manually upgrading it from its current version 5.2 to 6.1 with `dpkg -i` but it says that the new version conflicts with the new one.
So how can I safely reinstall VirtualBox so that I will still be able to my current VM?

PS. I think the problem with VirtualBox started after upgrading to the new kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem : virtualbox was installed once and the settings in your machine might be saved somewhere . Remove it completely with .

Uninstall virtualbox first:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox
```

install it again. Run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

This also help to fix broken packages, so if these commands above failed tried to fix packages first and then remove and install the virtualbox:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: What about my current virtual machine, will it stay unchanged?

Comment: If you want to be prepared for a case of your virtual machines can get lost, do a backups.
Make sure you save it on a separate USB or some king of external storage, before start to remove the old version of VBox

Comment: Purging the system files for VBox should not touch your VMs that're stored in your home directory elsewhere on disk.  You will have to reimport the VM but that's trivial after reinstallation.

Comment: it is strange that when I tried to uninstall, it said *Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not remove*